# nmap showing different results every time

Tags: networking, local-area-network, nmap

I am running:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.251.0/24
```

to see the hosts in the office network.
Every time that I run the command it shows a different result, for instance it sometimes shows

```
192.168.251.13
192.168.251.15
192.168.251.17
```

the next second it will show

```
192.168.251.13
192.168.251.17
```

the next second it will show

```
192.168.251.13
192.168.251.15
192.168.251.17
```

Basically it's intermittently showing ips of the hosts. What is the reason of this? I know the ips are not leaving/entering the network because they are either ip phones, or laptops connected using ethernet cable.
I don't know if it's related to this issue, but there are some wall jacks that suddenly stopped to work, so it looks like some some ethernet ports in the office are working, and others are not.

Comment: If you do this quickly this might be due to rate limiting, i.e. the other hosts on the LAN send ICMP echo reply packets at no more than one per second. Does this also happen if you let elapse more time (e.g. 10 seconds) between scans.